# Can’t manage to get this to work. Keep getting a repetition of not enough credit

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
choice="y"
again="y"
coin=0
credit=0
allowed=[0,10,20,50,100,200]
def money_insert():
    global again
    global coin
    global credit
    global allowed
    while again=="y":
        try:
            coin=int(input("insert coin"))
        except:
            print("thats not a coin")
        while coin not in allowed:
            print("invalid coin")
            coin = 0
        credit+=coin
        again=input("another coin y/n?")
money_insert()
print("you have",credit,"p")
print("")
print("**********")
print("**1 coke 100p**")
print("*2 haribo 100p*")
print("*3 galaxy 100p*")
print("**4 mars 100p**")
print("*5 crisps  50p*")
selection=int(input("what would you like? 1-5"))
while choice=="y":
  if selection==1:
    if credit>99:
      print("Here's your coke")
      credit-=100
    else:
        print("not enough credit")
        money_insert()
```

The last bit keeps displaying not enough credit continuously and I don’t know what to do

Sorry if this is a really dumb question I’m really new to python

Comment: Have you tried printing stuff in your function, or in loops, to see what might be happening?  Sometimes that is a good technique.  When do you want the `while choice=="y":` loop to end?

Comment: Your question just answered mine!

Comment: I really didn’t need the while choice=="y" thanks! There shouldn’t have been a loop to start with! Thanks

Comment: @justFathi I've been programming for about 5 years, and I still draw flow charts on paper before I go after a complicated project sometimes. Especially user interface situations where you end up with all sorts of menus and submenus with many choices.

Comment: You can answer your own question if you want so that it will have an answer or maybe consider @Aaron 's answer to accept. [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`choice` is never altered, so you can never escape the `while choice='y':` loop. Then assuming the selection chosen was `1` you continue on to buying your coke. If you have previously entered coins via the `money_insert` function, presumably you would have at some point answered no to the question "another coin y/n?". You never reset the `again` variable, so subsequent calls to `money_insert` will just skip your for loop and not let you enter more money. You then basically follow the same path over and over again: `while choice='y':` → `if selection==1:` → `if credit>99: ... else:` → `print("not enough credit")`

I should also like to point out the issue with your `money_insert` function is a direct result of using a global variable where you don't need to. Global variables can be useful in certain instances, but they are generally frowned upon for cases such as this where you generally assume running a function with the same inputs will give the same result, but since the global variable has changed, the function now behaves differently. In this instance you don't need `again` to be global because it isn't used anywhere else, so you can move `again='y'` inside the function definition and remove the line `global again` to solve that particular issue. The same applies to `coin` and `allowed` as they aren't used anywhere but inside the function, and although they aren't causing a problem at the moment, leaving them available outside the function to be changed could cause a problem if you try to name something else by the same name somewhere else.